# Is 桌上战争游戏 the term used for "Tabletop Wargaming / Miniwargaming"?

Tags: games, word-requests

Wargame is 战争游戏 and tabletop game is 桌上游戏 so I'm assuming that "Tabletop Wargaming" is 桌上战争游戏? Is this the term used?

This type of game is also called "Miniature Wargaming" or "Miniwargaming," is there another word for this is Chinese?

(I am referring to tabletop strategy war games played with miniature figures and terrain).

Comment: I played the miniature wargame when I was a little boy,but I never know the formal name of it .We call it "玩具兵大战",and there was a game called"Army men"(http://www.verycd.com/topics/2825805/).Do you mean this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least on the [Chinese Wikipedia article about Warhammer 4000](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%88%98%E9%94%A440000), 桌上战棋游戏 is used.

Comment: ahh i see that 战棋游戏 is synonymous with 战争游戏

Comment: Perhaps "minature wargaming" can be referred to as 微縮模型戰棋?

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer should be 陆战棋 or 军棋. Although in the original designs the pieces don't look like figures, the game rules are similar.

Comment: Reader note: 陆战棋, also known as 军棋, refers to a specific board game rather than a genre.